# Display Images onclick using Jsf graphics image tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces accordion which has a collection of images. I have rendered this images using jsf <`h:graphicImage>`tag using a servlet(Actually i display the thumbnail of the original image).

Want i want to do is that whenever a user clicks on a particular image in the accordion the same image should be displayed in my HTML5 canvas element.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Your question is very generic and vague. Where exactly are you stucking while writing code accordingly?

Comment: Hmm.. it goes likes this i have successfully displayed the images in the accordion, now when a user clicks on a particular image then that image should be displayed in my HTML5 canvas. I am not sure how to pass the value of the selected image to the canvas element. Unfortunately i cannot publish the code sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<h:graphicImage library="default" name="images/graph.png" onclick="draw(this.src);" />
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function draw(imgSrc) {
        console.log(imgSrc);
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrc;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(30, 96);
        ctx.lineTo(70, 66);
        ctx.lineTo(103, 76);
        ctx.lineTo(170, 15);
        ctx.stroke();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

More info: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial%2FUsing_images)